# error: expected initializer before '.' token

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация

Пытаюсь написать простенькую фонотеку, где класс содержит название и исполнителя трека.Пользователь должен ввести эти данные сам. Компилятору почему-то не нравятся строки "std::string another.title (UsersChoice);" и "std:: string another.performer(UsersChoice);". Пишет: error: expected initializer before '.' token.Считает, что созданный в main экземпляр класса Track неинициализирован?
Вот код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Track{
public:
string title;
string performer;

Track (string trackTitle, string trackPerformer)
{
title=trackTitle;
performer =trackPerformer;
};
};

int main()
{
char More = 'y';
vector <Track> vectorData;
string UsersChoice;
Track another ();

while (More== 'y')
{
cout << "Do you want to insert another track? Y/N"<< endl;
cin >> More;
if (More== 'y')
{
cout << "Insert the title of the track "<< endl;
getline (cin, UsersChoice);
std::string another.title (UsersChoice);

cout << "Insert the performer "<< endl;
getline (cin, UsersChoice);
std:: string another.performer(UsersChoice);

vectorData.push_back (another());
}
else break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Track another();` - это *объявление* **функции**, возвращающей `Track`.

`std::string another.title (UsersChoice);` - это попытка очередного *объявления* - но чего? `another.title` - это не новая переменная...

`vectorData.push_back(another());` - тут вы пытаетесь *вызывать* функциию/функциональный объект `another`. Который таковым не является.

Если исправить все это и добавить конструктор по умолчанию

```
Track() = default;
```

то все получится:

```
class Track{
public:
    string title;
    string performer;

    Track() = default;
    Track (string trackTitle, string trackPerformer)
    {
        title=trackTitle;
        performer =trackPerformer;
    };
};

int main()
{
    char More = 'y';
    vector <Track> vectorData;
    string UsersChoice;
    Track another;

    while (More== 'y')
    {
        cout << "Do you want to insert another track? Y/N"<< endl;
        cin >> More;
        if (More== 'y')
        {
            cout << "Insert the title of the track "<< endl;
            getline (cin, UsersChoice);
            another.title = UsersChoice;

            cout << "Insert the performer "<< endl;
            getline (cin, UsersChoice);
            another.performer = UsersChoice;

            vectorData.push_back(another);
        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Получится в смысле компиляции, но не работы: вы обнаружите, что после чтения `cin>>More` в буфере остается перевод строки, не дающий вам правильно вводить очередную строку...

Словом, я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    vector <Track> vectorData;

    for(char More = 'y'; More == 'y';
        cout << "Do you want to insert another track? Y/N: ",
        cin >> More, cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'))
    {
        std::string input1, input2;
        cout << "Insert the title of the track: " << endl;
        getline(cin, input1);
        cout << "Insert the performer: ";
        getline(cin, input2);
        vectorData.emplace_back(input1, input2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Кстати, при этом конструктор по умолчанию не нужен.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! Ну, раз уж Вы уделили мне время, позвольте Вас еще немного поэксплуатировать, а то я давно ищу по этим темам ответ в сети, но чего-то не нахожу.

Comment: Вы говорите, что мой цикл More не работает, но я проверяла, он  крутится пока n не нажмешь, если заранее (в конструкторе) присвоить членам какие-то строковые значения.  Что Вы имеете в виду под переводом строки, который остается в буфере? 3. Что все-таки значит "конструктор по умолчанию": я думала, это конструктор, присваивающий значения членам класса в объявлении класса, и использующиеся, если в main экземпляр создается без значений, как у нас. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: И еще один момент: в предложенной Вами версии input1 и input2 как-то попадают в класс Track? Через вектор это как-то происходит? А как вообще можно заполнить экземпляр класса пользователю с клавиатуры?

Comment: 1. Попробуйте у себя ввести y и нажать Enter - все, у вас title считается как пустая строка. Потому что в cin остается несброшенный Enter. 2. Конструктор по умолчанию - конструктор **без параметров** (ну, или со всеми параметрами со значениями по умолчанию). 3. Да, попадают - но этот экземпляр Track создается прямо в векторе, минуя все стадии создания и копирования объекта в вектор. Просто в этом случае его можно явно не создавать.

Comment: Harry, действительно, не успевала ввести title, а программа тут же запрашивала performer. Вставила укороченную версию cin.ignore (50, '\n'); все заработало. Спасибо большое еще раз!